# Pagination next/prev Jump, not working

Tags: magento2.3, pagination

In template file `Magento_Theme/templates/html/pager.phtml` the following code is never displayed:

```
<?php if ($block->canShowPreviousJump()): ?>
    <li class="item">
        <a class="page previous jump" title="" href="<?= $block->getPreviousJumpUrl() ?>">
            <span>...</span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif;?>
<?php if ($block->canShowNextJump()): ?>
    <li class="item">
        <a class="page next jump" title="" href="<?= $block->getNextJumpUrl() ?>">
            <span>...</span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif;?>
```

I am testing this in a category that has 35 pages of listing products. I'm browsing random pages.

I have also tried changing **Pagination Frame** and **Pagination Frame Skip** in magento configuration.

How does pagination jump work? What should I do to make it visible?

Comment: Does pagination is override by any module or theme?

Comment: Did you try expecting the element? THe code is visible but hidden? Or the code is not loaded at all? Can you provide URL?

Comment: @GerardoSiano the if clause returns false, so the jump html code is not displayed at all. If I remove if form the code, the jump html is displayed but not working. getPreviousJumpUrl() is null

Comment: @zekia, can you please check that in theme or extension? Did you remove the pagination from XML? <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar_pager" remove="true" />

Comment: @Kushal no theme or extension is not making any change on pagination. I have not removed pagination by xml. Pagination is displayed. The "jump" thing is not working.

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang there theme is not changing pagination. No extension too. As far as I know anyway.

Comment: To check and be confirm that the theme is doing something strange, 1st change theme to default luma and check it works or not. Then there is something wrong with the theme if it works out for luma theme.

Comment: @zekia it looks like there's something wrong with the theme. As already suggested, I would try to use Luma theme and check it the problem persists. Hope you have a staging site

Comment: can you share some more codes so I can try for you.

Comment: I have tried disabling custom theme and tested page with magento luma. The pagination jump is still not displayed. I need help to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution to this so I created a custom pager.phtml file, with the following changes:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["p"])){
    $current_page = $_GET["p"];
}else{
    $current_page = 1;
}
$last_page = $this->getLastPageNum();
$nextJumpLimit = $last_page-2;
$previousJumpLimit = 3;
$previousJump = 0;
$nextJump = 0;
if($current_page > $previousJumpLimit){
    $previousJump = 1;
}
if($current_page < $nextJumpLimit){
    $nextJump = 1;
}
?>

<?php if ($previousJump == 1): ?>
    <li class="item">
        <a class="page previous_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $block->getPageUrl($current_page-2); ?>">
            <span>...</span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($nextJump == 1): ?>
    <li class="item">
        <a class="page next_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $block->getPageUrl($current_page+2); ?>">
            <span>...</span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm posting this here, in case it helps somebody out there.

Answer (score 1):

What version of 2.3 are you on? 2.3.3 has a bug if you're using trailing slash / instead of a .html prefix is causing queries not to run. They apparently are actively working on a solution. 2.3.2-p2 is not experiencing this. Hopefully this will be fixed in 2.3.4 if they can agree on a fix:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18717

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25603

Comment: I'm using 2.3.0 but I'll check the links anyway

Comment: I don't think that this bug is related to my issue because I don't use / at the end of category list pages urls. I have category?p=4 links